# Firebase Storage Rule All Firebase Users or just users within my account?

Tags: firebase, security, permissions, storage, rules

We are building an android application and are taking some anonymous data which we want to store in a Firebase bucket. As we want to keep the data anonymous we do not want to create rules that are based on folders named with the user Id. However we only want users that have signed in via our app to have access to have write access to the bucket and no read access.

Does the below condition **request.auth != null** mean any users authenticated with Firebase have access or just users authenticated with Firebase users within our account / tenancy have access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the below condition request.auth != null mean any users authenticated with Firebase have access or just users authenticated with Firebase users within our account / tenancy have access?

The condition is used if you are using Firebase authentication in you project. It means if the user is authenticated in your project then they can have access